# Ms Access database does not input data from Visual Basic

Tags: database, vb.net, visual-studio, ms-access-2007

I'm currently experiencing a problem with exporting data from Visual Basic to my Ms Access file. When executing my form, I recieve the following error.."Update requires a valid UpdateCommand when passed DataRow collection with modified rows. It fails to export the data to Ms Access.

The purpose of this form is when a user writes in their new username and password, it is then exported into the Ms Access database and saves. I have another form that correctly imports the data from the database.

```
Public Class LoginTestV2

Private Sub LoginTestV2_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    'TODO: This line of code loads data into the 'DataDataSet.TblUserAccount' table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.
    Me.TblUserAccountTableAdapter.Fill(Me.DataDataSet.TblUserAccount)


End Sub

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnCreateAccount.Click
    Me.TblUserAccountTableAdapter.Fill(Me.DataDataSet.TblUserAccount)

    On Error GoTo SaveErr
    TblUserAccountBindingSource.EndEdit()
    TblUserAccountTableAdapter.Update(DataDataSet.TblUserAccount)
    MsgBox("You have created your account! You're on your way to start Recycling!")
SaveErr:
    Exit Sub
End Sub

Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnClose.Click
    Me.Close()
End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: This error message is usually caused by the inability of the TableAdapter to build an Update command at designtime. In turn, this is generally because you do not have a primary key defined ie it can't generate a 'Where' clause specifying a unique row to update.

Comment: What would be the solution to this problem Peter? As in, what specifically do I need to adjust my code with.

Comment: It's not a problem in your code itself. You need to look at the design of the  table in the db and/or the tableadapter in the dataset designer. The UPDATE command should be visible when you right-click the tableadapter and select properties. It's constructed automatically by the designer, if it can. If it can't, it's typically because it can't construct a WHERE clause that specifies a unique row to update, ie because there's no PK

Comment: Thank you for the reply. So I tried following along with your instructions. I went into Visual Basic, selected the tableadapter in the dataset designer and went to it's properties. I noticed the "Update Command" section was set to NONE. So I should be changing the settings of NONE or leave it as is?

Comment: Also, could the destination of where I have my database file cause a problem? I don't have it located in the debug folder.

Comment: In the designer, under advanced options, make sure 'Generate Insert, Update and Delete Statements' is checked. Also make sure you have a PK. If both these conditions are met, the designer should generate all three queries for you. I can't really go further than this in a comment - I suspect you need to research the TableAdapter designer a bit more. I found David Sceppa's ADO.Net book very helpful years ago. No, your .mdb file should not be in the debug folder; it's quite separate - it doesn't need to be on the same machine, even.

Answer (score 0):

Change the security settings of your access database . Right click the access database then check the allow all operation